# Restore/reset default Xcode font color scheme?

Tags: xcode

So I tried to click the "T" and accidentally clicked the "color" box in XCode's preferences for the font.

I was under "Default" already, now I'm trying to restore it. I'm finding this impossible. I got spoiled by the "reset defaults" button that exists in every other program. Anything besides reinstalling?

(yes, I'm partial to the white background that destroys my vision over time).

I've searched google and here for various permutations of this question, no luck. Perhaps there's a config file I need to find.

Comment: This is continuously upvoted over time by random people, making me think Apple didn't do usability tests on the IDE that much. (Along with the Xib tools, oh my god I get frustrated constantly)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Creating a new scheme by pressing the `[+]` button in the bottom of the list allows you to create a new scheme from a selection of *the un-modified templates*.

So to re-create the original `Default` scheme, you can just click the `[+]` button and select `Default`  -  it won't copy the scheme you accidentally modified from the list above, but from the original sources.

Comment: Oh my dog... that was simple, thanks! Sucks to be me, right after I lecture my friend for not poking at buttons when he's trying to learn programming, hehe

Comment: Wow, that's super helpful and ridiculously non-obvious!

Comment: I want to press upvote button so hard until I break it!