# How to restore Xcode default color scheme?

Tags: xcode, color-scheme

How to restore Xcode 10.2 default color scheme?

Tried the answer from here [Restore/reset default Xcode font color scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745137/restore-reset-default-xcode-font-color-scheme#) but unfortunately the "Default" does not appear after tapping the "plus" button. The only color schemes I can restore are the Default(light) and Default(dark) which are not the same as Default.

Is there a link from where I can download a "Default" config file and paste into some Xcode folder?